# Delphi 5 cast type to evaluated type causes Invalid typecast error

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

[image: debug time]

I need to convert a `Variant` to `TNotifyEvent`, but can't.

As the image shows I use `GetPropValue` to get the `OnClick` property of a `TMenuItem`. I must compare this to another `TNotifyEvent`, so I must convert it also to `TNotifyEvent`.

In runtime this is always type of `TNotifyEvent`, but the code not compile, when I try to cast it to `TNotifyEvent`.

How can I make it work? Unfortunately I have only Delphi version 5, so the RTTI capabilities are limited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling the wrong method. Instead of `GetPropValue` you need `GetMethodProp`. Like so:

```
TNotifyEvent(GetMethodProp(MenuItem, 'OnClick'));
```

Comment: :o shame on me, thenks for your answer